# Separating completed work from incomplete work in BIRT and Maximo

Tags: birt, maximo

So I start off with using a statement like:

```
select count(wonum)as workorder,gsasaddresscode,status from maximo.workorder where  istask=0 and
month(reportdate)=12 and year(reportdate)=2019 and worktype != 'PM' and status != 'CAN'
group by status,gsasaddresscode
```

The thing is we have 14 statuses(stati?) which basically end up being complete or incomplete, and that what I want to show.

```
Building  |Incomplete Work Orders | Complete Work Orders
AB002341  |       200             |        634
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Oracle:

```
 select sum(Complete), sum(Open) ,location from (
  select wo.status, wo.location,
 case when wo.status in (select SD.VALUE from synonymdomain sd where sd.domainid = 'WOSTATUS' and value ='CLOSE' or value = 'CAN'or value = 'COMP') then 1 else 0 end Complete,
 case when wo.status in (select SD.VALUE from synonymdomain sd where sd.domainid = 'WOSTATUS' and value ='APPR' or value = 'INPRG'or value = 'WAPPR') then 1 else 0 end Open
 from maximo.workorder wo  where  istask=0 and
 TO_CHAR (reportdate,'MM')= '12' and  TO_CHAR (reportdate,'YYYY') ='2019' and worktype != 'PM')
 group by location
```